# Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installation, installshield-le

I recently developed a program in VB.net with Access Database. And I want to create setup file of it.

I'd searched on "How to create setup file". And I got that using "Deployment and Installing" we can. After that I'd install "InstallShield". But that option does not appear inside Visual Studio.

I'm using "VS Express 2012 for Windows Desktop".

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Express 2012 does not support extensions, as such 3rd party products will not be able to provide additional functionality. The InstallShield LE page on MSDN spells this out clearly:

> InstallShield Limited Edition is free for users of all Visual Studio editions except the Express editions.
>
> <sup>Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531020.aspx</sup>

Your options are:

- Install [Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) (if you are allowed by the [license](https://www.visualstudio.com/support/legal/dn877550)) or buy Visual Studio Professional. These can be extended with either [Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/) or the [Visual Studio Setup Package extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d) or Installshield.
- Create a [click-once installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/748fh114.aspx)
- Use an installation system that is independent of Visual Studio and have it pick up your project output from a specific directory. You would have to author your installer outside of Visual Studio, e.g.:

  - [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)
  - [Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/) and [Wix Editor](https://www.wix.com/support/html5/editor/)